# Basement jack post on uneven support beams?

Tags: load, column

House is 100 years old. I'm looking to add a jack post as secondary support under a load bearing basement beam.  The load bearing beam is 3 2x12 together, with an additional 2x4 on each side to support ledge floor joists.   Where I want to add the jack post, 2 of the 2x12s are about a quarter inch lower than the other beams. Additionally, the metal plate on the post is only about 5 inches at the widest.

How should I place the top of the support post here?
Options considered are:

- use post as is with plate on 2 lower boards only
- add fat shims and a flat board of longer length to cover the span
- router the lower beams to be flush with the other 3

Comment: What is the beam's current span length? Distances to the load bearing supports running parallel to your beam? Is there a load bearing wall running on top of your beam? Is it bedrooms over the beam? What are you using for the post? The concern here is whether the beam will crush under the concentrated load. 400 psi should be a safe bearing stress for design. The weakest of the US softwoods is 405 psi if I remember correctly. Bedrooms get 30 psf live load and everything else is 40 psf live load. 10 psf is typically a safe value for dead load unless there's a topping slab, 3 layers of tile, etc.